# How to Set up SSRS Web Services to run under another port than 80?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server, ssrs-2008-r2

What steps do I have to pace to run Web Service URL and, Report Manager URL, under another port rather than 80? (DBMS is SQL Server 2008R2 and OS is WIn Server 2008R2).

Answer (score 1):

The port can be configured in SSRS Configuration Manager. This will have been installed on the machine when you installed SSRS.

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159261.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305(v=sql.105).aspx) BOL articles for all the details.

Comment: Initially thanks for your contribution ! however, much more effort is needed on IIS configuration than simply change the port on SSRS Configuration manager. I did it before posting this question and it didnt work for me !  If you have entire knowledge to lead me step by step on how configure the IIS to rout to SSRS web services please do !!!?